# How to serve static content in a Node Express container with Docker?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, docker, ejs

I used express generator to create a project, which automatically includes the public folder in app.js ...

I am trying to display an image in my index.ejs but it is not working ...
what would be the correct url to use?

After looking online it says that the src should be this img src="localhost:8000/images/1.png"

However, I am using docker toolbox, so I'm using the docker quick start terminal and I got it to work by using the docker i.p

so its like img src="127.432.343:8000/images/1.png" 
but that IP is specific to my computer I want my co-workers to be able to see the image without having to refactor the code ...

the name of my container is web so I also tried I tried      src="web:8000/images/1.png"

But this doesn't work, I feel like it should though, any tips please been trying for hours here.

Also if this were to go to production on a server, what would be the best way to do that? I don't want to have to change the code if I end up uploading it to AWS ...

Comment: Can you post the output of "docker ps"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static content in express must be in the /public folder. Images under public/images folder. If your image is in that folder, then it should be accessible from the url you're saying.

To show it from an ejs file, you need to only point to images/1.png (use a relative route):

```
<img src="images/i.png" />
```

This way, you won't have any trouble uploading it to any production server.

For other computers in your network to test your project, you need to check your computer's local network ip (ipconfig / ifconfig) and test with the ip address port 8000. Not every internal network has it's DNS fully configured.

Also check your computer's firewall to allow tcp traffic through port 8000. Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried images/1.png and no avail :/ is it because its in Docker and running through express? Basically its running on a VM, that my terminal is sshed into

Comment: Oh! with VM you should configure the VM to use Bridged Network. By default, they use NAT adapter.

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you can switch to [Docker for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/mac/#/docker-for-mac)? That would allow you to see it on localhost